# SQL use auto_increment column in where clause

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I want to use auto increment column in where clause when updating and deleting.

Like `update table set column1 = 'blahblah' where Index = 3;`

where 'Index' is auto increment column.

But the query doesn't work with syntax error.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

`index` is a keyword, unappropriate in `update` command

in sql-server you can fix the query with square brackets

```
update table set column1 = 'blahblah' where [Index] = 3
```

in mySql `` should do the trick

```
update table set column1 = 'blahblah' where `Index` = 3
```

Comment: My preference has been to \`Index\` with backticks surrounding schema, table and column names, as necessary

Comment: I'm using mysql, and the query doesn't work for me
with the message, 'Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warnings <0.00 sec>'

Comment: @Wook, it hard for me to say what is the issue. with Index written in back-quotes `` (not simple quotes '') syntax error is fixed and update worked for me on temporary table. do you have key = 3 in the table? and what is the warning?